# Изображения из Firebase storage в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-android

Как я могу загружать изображения получение из Firebase storage в `RecyclerView`?
Как должен будет выглядеть код адаптера, в котором происходит загрузка изображения в `ImageView`? Я использовал такой код для обычного получения изображения, но что делать в случае с адаптером?
Код:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference rootRef = storage.getReference();
islandRef = rootRef.child("images/island.jpg");

File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");

islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будем считать, что у вас на руках есть url для каждой картинки (полагаю, что Вы скачиваете именно по нему). Тогда проще воспользоваться готовым решением по инициализации картинки по URL. Например, вот так:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870638/how-to-use-setimageuri-on-android/48732019#48732019

Если же Вам именно нужен сам файл, например чтобы скачать его на диск, то адаптер стандартный для recyclerView, а в него, в качестве интерфейса-listener нужно ваш метод по загрузки картинки. =)